# Using live wallpaper with AppCompat theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, wallpaper

Is it possible to specify app/launcher background as live wallpaper when using AppCompat theme?
Samples uses Theme.Wallpaper, is there anything equivalent in AppCompat?
Specifying in theme xml is preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your own theme if you haven't already and set `android:windowBackground` to `transparent` and `android:windowShowWallpaper` to `true`.

Example:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Wallpaper" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
</style>
```